# Azure DevOps - query change history in backlog priority

Tags: azure-devops, workitem

I am using Azure DevOps services. How can I query change history in backlog priority in my work items?

Querying History field does not seem to be stable for that purpose. Are there any limitation related to that ability?

Answer (score 0):

Click Boards and you can see Queries under Boards. Click Queries to create a new query to query history as you want.You can refer to this ducument: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/queries/history-and-auditing?view=azure-devops&tabs=browser